# how to replace space with comma in perl

Tags: perl, file-handling

my perl program

```
open(my $inFileHandle, '<', '/home/Ram/Desktop/TCR/input_file_TCR_05_0.txt') or die " $!";
open(my $outFileHandle, '>', '/home/Ram/Desktop/TCR/input_file_TCR_05_0_ram.txt') or die " $!";

while (my $line = <$inFileHandle>)
{
    $line =~s/05 +/,/g;   
    print $outFileHandle $line;

}

close $inFileHandle;
close $outFileHandle;`
```

The result of the my program is

```
05,0,1–2,2,UN,praveen,kumar
05,0,3,1,UN, hari,krishna
05,0,4,1,UN,manju,nath
05,0,5–20,16,UN,sateesh,kumar
```

but i want out put like

```
05,0,1–2,2,UN,praveen kumar
05,0,3,1,UN, hari krishna
05,0,4,1,UN,manju nath
05,0,5–20,16,UN,sateesh kumar
```

Please suggest me what are the changes are need to achieve my output. Your suggestions will be appreciable

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1071703

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your actual program doesn't do `s/05 +/,/` but instead does `s/ /,/` or perhaps `s/ +/,/`.

If you want to only change some spaces to `,`, regex substitution is not ideal; I would instead do:

```
while (my $line = <$inFileHandle>)
{
    print join ',', split / /, $line, 6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is the input of your program, but I am considering the output you are receiving right now as the input (and of-couse, if `sed` is acceptable to you)

```
$ cat test
05,0,1–2,2,UN,praveen,kumar
05,0,3,1,UN, hari,krishna
05,0,4,1,UN,manju,nath
05,0,5–20,16,UN,sateesh,kumar

$ sed -r 's/(.*),(.*)$/\1 \2/' test
05,0,1–2,2,UN,praveen kumar
05,0,3,1,UN, hari krishna
05,0,4,1,UN,manju nath
05,0,5–20,16,UN,sateesh kumar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a slightly more complicated regex to match out the firstname/lastname pair, and run the substitution on everything before it, then concatenate the results for printing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

while (<>){
        chomp;
        if (/(.*?\s+)(\S+\s+\S+)$/){
                ($a,$b)=($1,$2);
                $a =~ s/\s+/,/g;
                $_ = $a.$b;
        }
        print $_."\n";
}
```